# How to select current logged in user to my selected option value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I got an interface, already logged in with a new username now I want so select this user to my selected option value and insert it into Mysql DB:

```
<select name="name" class="form-control" required="required">

    <option value="" required="required"> Please select </option>
    <option value="Rifadije Mavriqi"> Rifadije Mavriqi </option>
    <option value=" <?php                    

    
    ?>"></option>
    <option value="Merdiana Leci"> Merdiana Leci </option>
  
</select>
```

Comment: put logged user name in php session and compare this with options value

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still a bit unclear. Are you using `sessions/cookies`?

Comment: can you please give me an exemple... in my index page..i got this           :session_start();      
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['password']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: home.php");
 }

Answer (score 0):

Let say that your working with CronJobs that every X minutes check whos online, than select the column where online=1 with simple while and you got it.

Comment: HI capt.. as i am a bit new on it.... can you give a little example or explain me better.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i dont know if you ever work with cronjobs, thats really easy, via your cpanel/direct admin you pick up a file and set-up every x time the server will run this file. Let call this file cronj.php and there write a query that set all the online colum to 0 ( than unactive users resets) and close the file. I will add in a config or header file a query that check if this is user or unregister guy , if register lets set online colum to 1. And now via your control panel write select query with while that show you where online=1 and show you by the online colum the user names that online right now.